# How much Dry and soft(canned) dog food to feed 180 lb. E Mastiff?

Tags: dogs, diet

My question is, I am keeping our sons full grown e Mastiff for a while and have been feeding him 16 0z of Dry with 1 can of Pedigree in the am and 8 oz of dry and I/2 can soft food in the evening. Is this enough ?

Comment: can you add some information about the dogs acctivity level and the age of the dog.

Answer (score 2):

How much to feed has several variables.  But the quick answer is to look at the can/bag, it should have feeding instructions for dogs based on their weight for the quality of the food.

That is a guideline, if the dog is getting fat or skinning then you adjust the food accordingly.  Your vet should tell you what a healthy weight for your dog is during your regular visits.

Related:

- [Low Quality Dog Food - What are the risks?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/11182/low-quality-dog-food-what-are-the-risks)
- [Wet food vs. Dry food](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/17034/wet-food-vs-dry-food)
- [Is Royal Canin veterinary diet for dogs better than regular diet?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2134/is-royal-canin-veterinary-diet-for-dogs-better-than-regular-diet)
- [What does mg/kg in AAFCO's nutritional guidelines mean?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6958/what-does-mg-kg-in-aafcos-nutritional-guidelines-mean)
- [What should I monitor while changing my dog's diet?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/3175/what-should-i-monitor-while-changing-my-dogs-diet)
- [How can I help a dog to lose weight?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1062/how-can-i-help-a-dog-to-lose-weight)